# See the full git add patch

Tags: git, version-control, staging, git-add, git-patch

I use `git add -p` all the time. For large hunks I often go into (e)dit mode to review and adjust the hunk as desired.

Is there a way to edit the FULL diff (every hunk in every file), rather than make staging decisions one hunk at a time?

I know you can (s)plit a large hunk into smaller ones. I'm looking for something that kind of does the opposite: combine small hunks into one large one.

Comment: Something like `git diff >big.patch && vim big.patch && git apply big.patch && rm big.patch` ?

Comment: @phd Wonderful! I didn't know about git apply. This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you. I love SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Expanding from comment) Let's change the approach — use `git diff` + `git apply` instead of `git add`:

```
git diff >big.patch &&
vim big.patch &&
git apply big.patch &&
rm big.patch
```